# Display Modal Window once every 3 days with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, modal-dialog, jquery-cookie

I am trying to add carhartl's [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) script to my [modal script](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/) so that I can have the modal show only if a user has not been there/seen the modal for 3 days or if the user has recently cleared there cache.

Here's what I have so far...

This code currently launches my modal by auto clicking the button to launch the modal window and works perfectly. *(I know there might be a way to re-work this so that it just auto-loads the modal without need for a button, so if you can help me re-work that part I would appreciate it, also.)*

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;">
   <button class="md-trigger" id="modal11" data-modal="modal-11"></button>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#modal11').click();
});
</script>
```

But when adding the script the add a cookie to my modal, i seem to run into an issue, please view the code below and see where I am going wrong...

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;">
   <button class="md-trigger" id="modal11" data-modal="modal-11"></button>
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
         $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 3, path: '/' });
         $('#modal11').click();
      }
   });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide on this, I really appreciate your help! ;-)

---

here are my updates, based on @zigdawgydawg's help... but it's still not functioning for me...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#modal11').click(function();
});

console.log($.cookie('modal_shown'));
   if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
      console.log('creating cookie');
   $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
   $('#modal11').click();

}
console.log($.cookie('modal_shown'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: The code you've shared seems correct.  Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LP2Ra/1/).  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @zigdawgydawg - i tried your code, but this isn't launching the modal window even when I clear my cache...

Comment: Which browser are you using?  In Chrome's developer's tools, under the "Resources" tab, you can see (and delete) all the cookies for the current site.

Comment: @zigdawgydawg - im going to look into that right now, i updated the main post, with my code, does it look good?

Comment: Yes...the code you've shown should work. A couple of suggestions: 1) Remove all `console.log(...)` lines once you have it working, 2) Assuming that you are using the jQuery UI Dialog, instead of triggering the modal with `$('#modal11').click();`, use something like `$( "#id-of-your-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );`.

Comment: ok, so im getting an **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined** error on the **jquery.cookie.js** script, i'm going to do my edits [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QykSu/), so that you can play around with it... but i'm not sure, why its not working for me... - @zigdawgydawg

Comment: actually @zigdawgydawg, [here's an updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgAS5/), I made the js valid...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36945/discussion-between-jstormthakid-and-zigdawgydawg)

Comment: hey @mccannf, I read a similar answer from you on this topic, but it still doesn't seem to run for me.. is there any light you could shed on this?

Comment: As a result of our chat, I added a working example as an answer.  Please check it out and let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example that shows a dialog if the "modal_shown" cookie is not present.  Once the modal is shown, the cookie is added so that it won't show up again for 3 days.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3M9Wq/

You'll need to include these libraries/stylesheets: jQuery, jQuery UI, jQuery Cookie plugin, a jQuery UI theme CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">The dialog</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Initialize the dialog (initially hidden)
    $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});

    // Check for the "modal_shown" cookie.  If not found, show the dialog and add the cookie
    if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 3, path: '/' });
        $('#dialog').dialog("open");        
    }
});
```

Alternate jQuery that clicks a button instead of directly opening the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Check for the "modal_shown" cookie.  If not found, click the button and add the cookie
    if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 3, path: '/' });
        $('#modal11').click();     
    }
});
```

Comment: hey @zigdawgydawg - ok so that works, but thats not working with what I am doing...

Comment: ok so @zigdawgydawg - i think what's happening is that #modal11 is a button and the jQuery that currently works is "jQuery('#modal11').click();" but your code is not clicking anything, how would i edit this to click a button...

Comment: I added an alternate jQuery example that clicks the button instead.  It is very similar to your original code.  You might need to change all the `$`s to `jQuery`.  Is that what you need?

Comment: PERFECT!! WORKS PERFECTLY!!! Thanks so much @zigdawgydawg! BTW - Love your name, lol Thanks again!